# display string sub vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am new in C++, I created a struct called `Device` with two fields

- `string MacAdress`
- `vector<string> RSSI`

Then, I created a vector of structure: `vector<Device> Devices`

I want to extract the `vector<string> RSSI` and display its contant.

Here is where I got stuck in my main.cpp:

```
cout << "display MAC and RSSI"<< endl;

Device CurrentDevice;
for(int j=0; j<Devices.size();j++)
{
    CurrentDevice = Devices.at(j);

    vector<string>::const_iterator begin = CurrentDevice.GetRSSIs().begin();
    vector<string>::const_iterator last = CurrentDevice.GetRSSIs().begin() + CurrentDevice.GetRSSIs().size();
    vector<string> intermed(begin+1, last);
    cout << "Size: "<< intermed.size() << endl;

    for (int i = 0 ;  i < intermed.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << intermed[i] << endl;

    cout << "device n°"<< j+1<<" " << "MAC "<< " "<< CurrentDevice.GetMacAdress()<< endl;

    for(int k=0; k<intermed.size();k++)
    {

        cout << "device n°" << j;
        cout << "\tRSSI " << k << " = " << intermed.at(k)<< endl;
    }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I end up with Size=0

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Please edit your post so that it's a [mcve], and explain clearly what your question is.

Comment: Please specify an example set of your data. Describe exactly, how many items Devices contains, what is the content RSSI for each item and what is your expected size / output.

Answer (score 1):

here is some simplified code that does not use iterators but should still do the job:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    struct Device {
        std::string MacAddress;
        std::vector<std::string> RSSI;

    };

    std::vector<Device> Devices;

    // add some stuff to first object
    Device CurrentDevice1;
    CurrentDevice1.MacAddress = "A-B-C";
    CurrentDevice1.RSSI.push_back("rssi11");
    CurrentDevice1.RSSI.push_back("rssi12");
    CurrentDevice1.RSSI.push_back("rssi13");

    Devices.push_back(CurrentDevice1);

    // add some stuff to second object
    Device CurrentDevice2;
    CurrentDevice2.MacAddress = "D-E-F";
    CurrentDevice2.RSSI.push_back("rssi21");
    CurrentDevice2.RSSI.push_back("rssi22");

    Devices.push_back(CurrentDevice2);


    // see object MAC's
    for (int i = 0; i < Devices.size(); i++){
        std::cout << "device " << i+1 << " MAC: " << Devices[i].MacAddress << std::endl;
    }

    // see object RSSI's
    for (int j = 0; j < Devices.size(); j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < Devices[j].RSSI.size(); k++){
            std::cout << "device " << j + 1 << " RSSI: " << k +1 << " : " << Devices[j].RSSI[k] << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what do you want to obtain, but I suppose the problem is in the following lines

```
vector<string>::const_iterator last = CurrentDevice.GetRSSIs().begin() + CurrentDevice.GetRSSIs().size();
vector<string> intermed(begin+1, last);
```

Do you want to obtain a copy of `CurrentDevice.GetRSSIs()`?

In this case, you can use `begin()` and `end()`

```
vector<string> intermed(CurrentDevice().GetRSSIs().begin(),
                        CurrentDevice().GetRSSIs().end());
```

or, simpler, invoke the copy constructor,

```
vector<string> intermed(CurrentDevice().GetRSSIs());
```

Comment: The problem is that I get  MacAdress and RSSI from a command line, so I can't add them manually.
For one MacAdress I have a vector of RSSIs, each time I get a new RSSI I have to add it at the end of the RSSI vector